# Best way to normalize a table

Tags: sql, database-design, database-normalization

Need suggestions on what would be the best way to normalize the following table:

Earlier, I had a table:

```
personId    year    dob    column1    column2    column3
--------    ----    ---    -------    -------    -------
```

Here, (`personId+year`) was the primary key, and columns `dob`, `column1`, `column2` and `column3` had unique values.

Now, according to a new requirement  `column1`, `column2` and `column3` will be storing multiple values. In a very naive sense, it is supposed to hold values like:

```
personId    year    dob       column1    column2    column3
--------    ----    ------    -------    -------    -------  
       1    2018    2.1.20    A1, A2     B1         C1, C2, C3
```

I simply do not want to normalize it till First Normal Form, but want to break it into more tables, like:

Table 1:

```
personId    year    dob       
--------    ----    ------    
       1    2018    2.1.20
```

Table 2:

```
personId    year    column1   
--------    ----    ------    
       1    2018    A1    
       1    2018    A2
```

Table 3:

```
personId    year    column2   
--------    ----    ------    
       1    2018    B1
```

Table 4:

```
personId    year    column3   
--------    ----    ------    
       1    2018    C1      
       1    2018    C2    
       1    2018    C3
```

Now Table 1 looks fine to me as it still has a PK of (`personId`+`year`), but Tables 2-3 don't look very elegant as they lack a primary key.

Are there better ways to achieve this?

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook/manual with a bespoke tutorial. Follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Ask a specific researched non-duplicate question where stuck. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS This isn't clear about what you want. "fine", "don't look very elegant" & ["better"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461/266284) don't mean anything. "achieve this"-What, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You are close.  You should introduce a new primary key for the first table and I would recommend primary keys for the others as well:

Table 1:

```
t1Id   personId    year    dob       
   1       1       2018    2.1.20
```

Table 2:

```
t2Id    t1Id    column1   
  1       1      A1    
  2       1      A2
```

Table 3:

```
t3Id    t1id    column2   
  1       1       B1
```

Table 4:

```
t4Id    t1id    column3   
  1       1       C1      
  2       1       C2    
  3       1       C3
```

If ordering is important, you may also want to include a sequential numbering column in all but the first table.

In addition, the data columns in the last three tables should perhaps be ids to their own tables.